# Custom awaitable and resumption with ASIO coroutines

Tags: c++, asynchronous, networking, coroutine, asio

I have the following class representing a connection in ASIO (I omitted the bits not pertinent to the issue):

```
template<Enumeration T>
class connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<connection<T>> {

    ...
    // Thread-safe queue
    ts_queue<message<T>> m_qMessagesIn;
    std::coroutine_handle<> m_resumeCoro{};
    ...

  public:
    ...

    asio::awaitable<void> listen() {
        auto self = this->shared_from_this();
        for (;;) {
          auto ret = co_await (readMessage() || watchdog());
          if (ret.index() == 1)
             co_return;
 
          ...
          auto& msgOpt = std::get<std::optional<message<T>>>(ret);
          if (not msgOpt.has_value())
             co_return;
          auto& msg = msgOpt.value();

          m_qMessagesIn.push_back(std::move(msg));
          
          // ==================================================
          // THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO
          if (m_resumeCoro)
             m_resumeCoro.resume();
          ...
      }
```

I would like to resume a coroutine that is `co_await`ing the arrival of a message once it  happens. I tried to accomplish it by placing another function inside the class:

```
    auto message() {
      struct awaitable {
        connection* m_pConn;
        std::optional<message<T>> m_msg;

        awaitable(connection* pConn) : m_pConn{ pConn } {}

        bool await_ready() { return m_pConn->hasMessage(); }
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> coro) {
          // Save handle for later resumption
          m_pConn->m_resumeCoro = coro;
        }
        auto await_resume() { 
          m_pConn->m_resumeCoro = nullptr;
          return std::move(m_pConn->m_qMessagesIn.front());
        }
      };
      return awaitable{ this };
   }
};
```

This should suspend the calling coroutine and save the handle until a message is received, upon which the coroutine will be resumed. Usage of this would look like this:

```
asio::awaitable<void> useConnection() {
   connection<T> conn = ...;
   ...
   auto msg = co_await conn.message(); // <-- DOESN'T COMPILE
   // error: no matching member function for call to 'await_transform'
}
```

Alas, this does not compile. I'm assuming that has to do with the intricate inner workings of ASIO and that I'm not supposed to do something like this. I have already looked into `async_initiate`, but I'm not sure whether this is going to help me.

Therefore my question is: what would be the "correct" way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Async initiate is what you're looking for, it's just really not ergonomic and not well documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've been able to figure out how to do this. Here's how I did it in case anyone runs into the same issue.

`async_initiate` provided the solution after all. The handler passed to the function object that is passed to `async_initiate` is what's responsible for resuming and returning a value to the expression `co_await`ing the coroutine. Therefore, inside the lambda the handler can be added to a queue of handlers inside the class for later invocation, which is tantamount to resuming the coroutine and returning a value:

```
template<Enumeration T>
class connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<connection<T>> {

    ...
    // Thread-safe queue
    ts_queue<message<T>> m_qMessagesIn;
    // C++23's std::move_only_function used here, because the handler is not copyable,
    // which would be required by a plain old std::function
    ts_queue<std::move_only_function<void(ice::net::message<T>)>> m_qfnMessageReturners{};
    ...

  public:
    ...

    asio::awaitable<void> listen() {
        auto self = this->shared_from_this();
        for (;;) {
          auto ret = co_await (readMessage() || watchdog());
          if (ret.index() == 1)
             co_return;
 
          ...
          auto& msgOpt = std::get<std::optional<message<T>>>(ret);
          if (not msgOpt.has_value())
             co_return;
          auto& msg = msgOpt.value();

          m_qMessagesIn.push_back(std::move(msg));
          
          // ===========================================
          // CALL THE HANDLER BELOW, THEREBY RETURNING THE MESSAGE TO THE
          // co_await'ING EXPRESSION
          if (not m_qfnMessageReturners.empty()) {
            auto func = std::move(m_qfnMessageReturners.front());
            m_qfnMessageReturners.pop_front();
            
            auto msg = std::move(m_qMessagesIn.front());
            m_qMessagesIn.pop_front();
            
            std::move(func)(std::move(msg));
          }
          ...
      }
```

The `message` function from my question then becomes this:

```
        template<typename CompletionToken>
        auto message(CompletionToken&& token) {
          return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(ice::net::message<T>)>(
              [self = this->shared_from_this()](auto&& handler) mutable {
                // Return message at the front of the queue if there is one
                // immediately...
                if (not self->m_qMessagesIn.empty()) {
                  auto msg = std::move(self->m_qMessagesIn.front());
                  self->m_qMessagesIn.pop_front();
                  // Calling the handler means returning the value to the
                  // coroutine that co_awaits message().
                  std::move(handler)(std::move(msg));
                } else 
                // ... otherwise save handler for when a message arrives
                {
                  self->m_qfnMessageReturners.emplace_back(std::move(handler));
                }
              },
              token);
        }
```

Alternatively, hard-coded for use with `asio::use_awaitable` (i.e. for use with coroutines), we could write:

```
        auto message() {
          return asio::async_initiate<decltype(asio::use_awaitable), void(ice::net::message<T>)>(
              [self = this->shared_from_this()](auto&& handler) mutable {
                 ...
              },
              asio::use_awaitable);
        }
```